# Quiz, is their answer wrong?

Tags: javascript

I had this question in a test.

What is the output of the following **incorrect** javascript code and what is the error?

```
num=0;
if (num > 10);
{
    num = num + 10;
}
alert(num);
```

**The possible answers:**

a) Output 10. There should not be a semicolon(;) at the end of the if statement `if(num > 10)`

b) Output 0
   There should not be quotes around the num in the alert statement `alert("num");`

c) Output 10. There should not be a semicolon(;) at the end of the if statement `if (num > 10)`

d) Does not execute at all. There is an error with the calculation `num = num + 10;. num == num + 10;`

**My answer is:**

As is it would not execute, but if we removed the semicolon after if statement, and added var it would. The output would be zero.

This is because num is not greater than 10, therefore the `if statement` doesn't do anything. num still = 0.

There should be no semicolon after the `IF statement`. var should be used in front of the num variable.

Their answer was a).the output would be 10, and there should be no semicolon after `if statement`.

The statement doesn't work, but if we tidy it up the answer would still never be 10.

**Is the question a poorly written question? Are they wrong, or am I wrong?**

Comment: The question answers are confusing. A and C are the same. The output is 10. If no strict mode is set, there's no need to use var in order to the code be valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A semicolon after an `if` condition is *not* a syntax error, unfortunately - it just means that the result of the `if` condition is not used, because no statements run if it's true.

The `{` immediately following it is valid syntax, despite being disconnected from the `if` - it's a bare block. Bare blocks are valid too, but pretty weird - they *mostly* just create a new scope that `const` and `let` variables declared inside do not leak out of.

```js
num=0;
if (num > 10);
{
num = num + 10;
}
alert(num);
```

See how "Run code snippet" results in 10 popping up.

The quiz is correct.

Comment: I stand corrected, the example alerts 10, and was not what I expected. Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Since there's a semicolon after the `if` statement, it essentially has no body and therefore nothing to run if it's true. You can think of it as ending at the semicolon.

Block statements (statements inside of brackets, `{}`) are valid in Javascript and, in this case, would just run like normal code. So the `num = num + 10` runs. Since the `if` statement above ended at the semicolon, this code runs regardless of the result of the `if` statement. Think of it as having nothing to do with the `if` statement.

So the result is `10`. And yes, you likely want to remove the semicolon after the `if` statement to get the desired result.

You can test it out if you want:

```js
num=0;
if (num > 10);
{
num = num + 10;
}
alert(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a semicolon after the if statement, the if statement is ignored.

The statements inside the block will be executed so the below code executes :

```
num = num+10
```

And you get 10 as your answer.